# SSMS - SQL - There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these before closing the window?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whenever I try to close a tab I am getting the error below. Even when I run a simple SELECT statement. I don't know if I need to change a setting or have configured something incorrectly.

*There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these before closing the window?*

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check in the settings under Query Execution -> SQL Server -> ANSI if "SET IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS" and/or "SET ANSI_DEFAULTS" is checked. If so, hit that "reset to default" button to uncheck it; you never want that.

Comment: @MEdwin gosh you mean "rollback transaction". LOL Not sure that is really the issue here though.

Comment: @MEdwin I understand how that works. Did you see the comment from Jeroen above? My guess is that is what is happening. But yes when closing a tab in SSMS it checks @@TRANCOUNT to see if there is an open transaction. It doesn't sound like the OP has created a transaction. I have seen the behavior before with IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS turned on by mistake.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have just tried this and it still isn't working. Also every time I close and reopen SQL it will reset the setting to tick all the boxes apart from "SET ANSI_DEFULTS". No idea whats happening.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you execute `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF` explicitly in your query window before doing anything else? As to the settings, it sounds like you may be running with an account that lacks permissions to change the settings (possibly an admin tampering with the registry?)